# HttpContext.Current.Session keep return Object reference not set to an instance of an object on my class (MVC 5)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, powershell, session, asp.net-web-api

I have class to keep PowerShell session. So that I can access the powershell session without to create a new session . Below is my snippet code

```
public class PowerShellSession : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public PowerShell PowerShell2010()
    {
        if(HttpContext.Current.Session == null)
        {
            WSManConnectionInfoSession connExch = new WSManConnectionInfoSession();

            var session = connExch.GetExchangeConnectionSession(2010);

            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(session);
            runspace.Open();
            PowerShell Shell = PowerShell.Create();
            Shell.Runspace = runspace;
            HttpContext.Current.Session["PowerShell2010"] = Shell;

            return Shell;
        }
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["PowerShell2010"] != null)
        {
            WSManConnectionInfoSession connExch = new WSManConnectionInfoSession();

            var session = connExch.GetExchangeConnectionSession(2010);

            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(session);
            runspace.Open();
            PowerShell Shell = PowerShell.Create();
            Shell.Runspace = runspace;
            HttpContext.Current.Session["PowerShell2010"] = Shell;

            return Shell;
        }
        else
        {
            return (PowerShell)HttpContext.Current.Session["PowerShell2010"];
        }       

    }
}
```

The problem is my code always return "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object" when I try to set value to session.

Here the code to set value on session

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["PowerShell2010"] = Shell;
```

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Is the `HttpContext.Current.Session` a dictionary? You should set add a watch for it and see what the value is before you try to set it to `Shell`.

Comment: At no point do I see you set the session. your first if condition enters if `HttpContext.Current.Session` is `null`. You don't assign a session to the property yet try to access it when you just proved that it is `null`

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience using Powershell. Having said that, a big part of the problem seems to be that your `if()` statements are incorrect.

First you check `if(HttpContext.Current.Session == null)` which is TRUE if the Session object can not be found in the current context. But then you proceed by attempting to use that Session object anyway, so no wonder you get the error that you are getting.

The next one seems wrong too: `if (HttpContext.Current.Session["PowerShell2010"] != null)`, which would be TRUE if a previous attempt to store a Powershell object was successful. But then you proceed to create and store a new Powershell object, which totally defeats the cache that you apparently wanted. You need to replace this with `== null`, assuming that you will find a way to get to the Session object in the first place.

And last but not least, to have a bigger chance of getting to the HTTP Session object:

- make sure that Session state is enabled in your web server and/or Web.Config files;
- run as much of the code above in an MVC Controller class, instead of in a Type Library class or something like that. Or pass the HTTP Session object from the MVC Controller Action-method into the Type Library method using a parameter.